# Does text-shadow CSS affect SEO ranking by risking a cloaking penalty?

Tags: seo, css, search-results, penalty, cloaking

I've done googling this but didn't found any answers and would love to try this out on my website.

As it's a good ranking website, I want to ask you before risking it.

```
   font-size: 50px;  
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ddd,
                 0px 2px 1px #d6d6d6,
                 0px 3px 1px #ccc,
                 0px 4px 1px #c5c5c5,
                 0px 5px 1px #c1c1c1,
                 0px 6px 1px #bbb,
                 0px 7px 1px #777,
                 0px 8px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4),
                 0px 9px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1),
                 0px 10px 7px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.15),
                 0px 11px 9px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2),
                 0px 12px 11px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.25),
                 0px 13px 15px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}
```

Is this okay? OR CHECK THIS http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/urkCd

Comment: Why do you think this would affect SEO?

Comment: Because one thing Google penalize the site which uses same text color for keywords as for the background to hide the K/W, cloaking basically. So this 3d effect CSS has white on the back and red on top that's how it's 3d, will it affect SEO?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google penalizes for text that is not visible to the users.  White text on a white background can be used for keyword stuffing.  In that case the keywords are put in the page source where Googlebot indexes them, but the font color makes it so that users don't see it.

Shadow text is not cloaking because the user can see it clearly.  There is no risk of penalty of using CSS text-shadow.

Answer (score 1):

HTML code and CSS code errors if written poorly or outdated **don't** really matter for actual SEO and rankings on thier own.

Unless these erros are causing other issues such as user experience which would increase bounce rates and affect rankings.

Comment: But are you aware of Cloaking seo?

Comment: Shadow is not cloaking mate.